# Не понимаю как сделать два разных ивента click у объектов в ObjectManager (yandex map api)

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

У меня есть **ObjectManager** в которые я добавляю объекты.

```
function createStation(coordinates, nameOfMyPolygon, background, id) {
      objectManager.add({
          type: 'Feature',
          id: id,
          geometry: {
              type: 'Polygon',
              coordinates: coordinates
      },
      properties: {
        name: nameOfMyPolygon
      },
      options: {
          fillColor: background,
          labelDefaults: 'light',
          labelLayout: '{{properties.name}}'
      }
      });
    }
```

и я использую эту функцию 100 раз и создаю и добавляю 100 объектов. 
Вот такой код я использую чтобы навесить на все объекты в менеджере объектов ивент click

```
objectManager.events.add('click', () => {
   popupSectionInfo.classList.add('active');
   priceSectionPopup.classList.remove('top');
   popupSectionInfo.classList.add('top');
});
```

---

А теперь то что я не могу понять. **Как мне навесить на два разных объекта, два разных ивента click?** Буду рад если сможете привести пример.

P.s. Я читал документацию и я нашел фильтры, но я разобрался только как отобразить тот или иной объект, а как навесить ивент на разные объекты не понял... Вот ссылка https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/ObjectManager-docpage

Comment: В общем случае, это в одном обработчике определить условие, по которому будет обрабатываться тот или иной объект.

Comment: вы можете определять, на каком объекте был клик, через e.target и через if в зависимости от объекта выполнять нужное действие.

Comment: Когда я вывожу e.target он выдает undefined.

Comment: Вот код
 objectManager.events.add('click', (e) => {
        console.log(e.target);
        popupSectionInfo.classList.add('active');
        priceSectionPopup.classList.remove('top');
        popupSectionInfo.classList.add('top');
    });

Comment: нужен весь пример кода целиком

Comment: Вот весь код https://codepen.io/zilermand/pen/KRgxBM

Comment: Ну так не пойдет) Вам в теории написали два варианта, как можно решить задачу - если что-то не получается, нужен полный пример рабочей карты с выводом объектов, чтобы проверять только единственную проблему с кликом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем два разных ивента я сделать не смог, но с помощью e.get('objectId'), можно найти id объекта и по нему уже обрабатывать то что вам будет нужно.